# Mixamo Rig And Mesh Problem

Tags: animation, mesh, rigging, weight-painting

i drawn a cubic style character and i set weights properly from blender. But when i upload and autorig my character from mixamo, i'm getting weird issue that my mesh is stretching as you can see from belowed image.[image: **enter image description here**]

Answer (score 1):

I think rig effects to vertices try to add loopcuts bending areas and reupload to mixamo again probably it will work

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue, Id advise using FBX for mixamo - upload and download.